# Adding Font to Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, fonts

Is it possible to add Custom fonts to Windows Phone 7 system fonts?
I have Windows Phone 7.5 (Lg C900) and it doesn't support Georgian font.
I want to add font to Windows Phone's OS, not to an application.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to add new fonts or language support to Windows Phone 7 beyond what is already available. Windows Phone 8 does have additional language support, though.

The official MSDN docs have a great list of all supported languages and illustrate the differences between the two platforms...

**Culture and Language support**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202918(v=vs.105).aspx

**UI Font support**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202920(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_SupportedUIFontsinWindowsPhone

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible in windows phone. Add custom font file in your solution.And then add following line of code in App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources><FontFamily x:Key="QUARTZMS">/Fonts/QUARTZMS.TTF</FontFamily></Application.Resources>
```